# plone: folder view pagination

Tags: plone, zope

We are using Plone 4.1.3, and would have pagination in the Plone folder_full_view.  Specifically, we want to have pagination for a folder containing News items so that the folder_full_view will not display all our news items in one single page (many items causing very slow page load time).    That is, we want the first page of the folder to display say the latest 5 News items, and the next page of the folder to display the next latest 5 News items, and so on.

Collection (which has pagination) is not suitable for us because collection does not allow users to add items to it.   We want our users to be able to add News item themselves.

We found this documentation in Plone: Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.content-2.0.7-py2.6.egg/plone/app/content/batching.txt and Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.content-2.0.7-py2.6.egg/plone/app/content/browser/tests/foldercontents.txt, but the instructions are very vague and we don't know how to go about it.

Is there a way to modify folder_full_view using ZMI so that folder_full_view (or whatever folder view) will have pagination (i.e. how to customize, rename, add to Available View Types in portal_types/Folder).

We found something here: http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/pagination-in-plone-folders-td339336.html
But again it is very vague.

Can somebody advise?

Thank you very much in anticipation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this, and a good "Plone best practice" is to create a folder to contain your news items, then create a Collection inside the folder, then set that Collection as the default view for the folder.  Users will be able to add news items to the folder, and the Collection will let you take advantage of batching.

Comment: Okay, got it, thank you.   But do you know how to do it by modifying the folder view in ZMI?

Comment: I don't, sorry. Trust me, do it my way and life will be much easier. :-)

Comment: Thank you Jon.  I just wanted to learn how to use the batching commands.   Anyway, I have used the method you suggested on my site.  thank u once again.